# How can I combine static js, css and bower packages(lib) files from supporting project into my main web project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to combine two projects into one solution without mixing the projects. The projects use different versions of bootstrap, different versions of jquery and both use versions of angular which means I have templates etc. in the wwwroot folder of both projects.  Right now I have a working solution in which I have renamed various components and stuffed them in the wwwroot folder structure. Those asp.net mvc views in the dependent project are served as resources from the dll project just fine using embedded file resources like this:

```
            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(MainStarController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
        });
```

I can't figure out how to create a resource of the other files.

There is a solution for adding additional non-standard static file locations within the primary project:

```
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
      Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"node_modules")),
  RequestPath = new PathString("/vendor")
});
```

But this appears to only deal with secondary locations in the primary project.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What about using WebPack (or similar) to bundle up each project's dependencies into a single `.css` and .`js` file per project?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks and I will ultimately use WebPack when I start bundling each project.  The problem is that the second project needs to be fully encapsulated in it's own dll.  You can do this with an MVC core 2.0 project, but the instant you want to include third party tools like angular etc. in the second project you lose encapsulation because those items must reside in the wwwroot of the primary web project.